# I decided I've had enough vs I decided I'd had enough

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

Today I heard a native English speaker teacher use `We decided we have had enough` while telling a story. I am somewhat familiar with the notion of *Sequence of tenses* and thought the correct usage was `We decided we had had enough` where the `have had` should have backshifed to `had had` similarly to what happens in reported speech.

Am I misinterpreting the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backshifting isn't mandatory in all cases, and in particular, when reporting something that you believe is still true, you often don't backshift.

Consider, yesterday, John said, "My mother lives in Wales."

Today you report what John said:

> John said that his mother lives in Wales.

You don't have to backshift because you believe that today she still lives in Wales.  On the other hand if you are not sure if it is still true you would backshift.

> Twenty years ago, John said that his mother lived in Wales, I'm not sure if she still does.

Similarly here.  The speaker has "had enough" and this is still true today, so she chooses not to backshift. On the other hand, if she was talking about things long ago, she may well have backshifted because her feeling of having "had enough" was no longer present.

> 20 years ago we bought a house because of the trouble with landlords. When our landlord doubled the rent and refused to repair the boiler we decided we'd had enough....